# How do I connect a storyboard Table View to a class that I have created?

Tags: swift

I am currently working on my first app in Swift 5, using Xcode 11.2.1, for the iOS. In the Main.storyboard file I have created a Tab Bar controller, that is also an Initial View controller. The tab that shows up right after booting the app up contains a Table View. I would like to update the cells in the said Table View, and in order to do so I have created a class - DBHandler.swift.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SQLite

class DBHandler{
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "db1", ofType: "sql")
    lazy var db = try! Connection(path!, readonly: true)

    func getSessionTitles(){
        let data = Table("data")
        let id = Expression<String>("id")
        for one in try! db.prepare(data) {
            print("id: \(one[id])")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that anytime I try to control-drag the Table View into my DBHandler class the app builds, and then crashes with `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x7ff4af6065c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key TableView.'`error. In the storyboard, after control-clicking the View there is a yellow triangle in the Outlets section that says `UIView does not have an outlet named TableView`. The UIView is the class that shows up in the "Custom Class" section in the Identity Inspector of the Table View, however my custom class doesn't show up there.

How could I connect the Table View to the DBHandler class so that I could insert some data into the Table View?

Comment: why are you using SQLite? CoreData is a great tool that is very easy to use

Comment: There are many things that could be changed to make this work, but I'd suggest your time would be better spent running through a couple of the many tableView tutorials that are available online to get a grasp of the fundamentals to building a tableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
Class DBHandler: UITableViewController{
    //your code here
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "db1", ofType: "sql")
    lazy var db = try! Connection(path!, readonly: true)

    func getSessionTitles(){
        let data = Table("data")
        let id = Expression<String>("id")
    //for one in try! db.prepare(data) {
        //print("id: \(one[id])")
    //}
  }
}
```

Make sure that in the storyboard identity inspector that your table view is conformed to your custom class DBHandler.

Edit -

You shouldn’t be using the try statement in the code provided.
Your class for the table view controller should not try and grab from the database. 
Write a function that does that separately

Comment: probably simpler to make the `DBHandler` conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol and set the `dataSource` property of the `tableView` to the `DBHandler`

Comment: @ ɯɐɹʞ  I dont think that makes it "simpler", it is simply a different way of doing it. Here the tableViewController is whats being defined as the class so setting the datasource equal to the DBhandler will still require setup and implementation. That being said it would probably have less lines of code to write.. if thats what simpler means to you

Comment: `DBHandler` is not a `UIViewController`, so it complicates things to force it to be one. view controllers should not directly access DBs; there should be a DB interface to reduce the complexity and promote loose coupling. it makes it much simpler to have a database handler be a datasource unless implementing all logic in a view controller is considered simple. I call it spaghetti code, or MVC (Massive View Controller)

Comment: @ɯɐɹʞ Even though the DBHandler is not a viewController, forcing it to be a tableViewController does NOT mean it will directly access the DB. By forcing it to be a UITableViewController, it allows the tableView implemented to use the code within the class. That being said, it is probably not good practice to have this DB code within a class at all. It should be its own function that retrieves information, then that information should be placed into a dictionary (or whatever) to then be updated by the table View

Comment: @ɯɐɹʞ  I understand the confusion. It’s because of the try statement in the code. I agree yes this should not be there

Comment: It’s only bad practice if he continues to use the try statement, i will edit answer